# JQuery: Getting number from html element and alter it in Jquery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some number printed on my html for special usage, therefore i need to grab it from html, alter it in javascript and output again.

So i have few numbers like below in my HTML:

```
<p id="usage">6564</p>
```

and i'd like to have a if statment in order do some modifcation of "6564",
below is some pseudo codes, which tells what i'd like to do.

```
var checker = $("#usage").html();

if(checker >= 2 digits){
  //display the first two digits 
}
else {
  $("#usage").html("1");
}
```

**The if statement should  display the first two digits only, if the number has more than 2 digits otherwise it will return "10"**,  So the result should be "65"

**Solution :**

For people who experience the same issues as me

```
var checker = $(".totalPage").text().replace(/,/g, ""); //it you have comma between your number like 6,545
var pagevalue = parseInt(checker.slice(0,2));

        if(checker.length >= 2){
          $(".totalPage").text(pagevalue+1);//you can modify the our put even further 
        }
        else {
          $(".totalPage").text("10");
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var checker = $("#usage").text();

if(checker.length >= 2){
  $("#usage").text(checker.slice(0,2));
  
}
else {
  $("#usage").text("10");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="usage">6564</p>
```

1. Use slice to get the 2 digits.
2. Use length to tell if number has more than 2 digits

Comment: am i able to covert the output to integer, since we use .slice() to split it?

Comment: it wasnt int to begin with you can parse it if you want integer

Comment: parseInt(var checker = $(".totalPage").text(checker.slice(0,2))+1; is this alright?

Comment: you can have something like `var newvalue = parseInt(checker.slice(0,2)+1)` do you need to increment it before putting it to the html?

Comment: @anson920520 glad to help happy coding mate

Answer (score 1):

Here's the pure Js version.

```js
function extractFunction() {      

   var checker =  document.getElementById("usage").innerHTML; 
  
  if (checker.length > 2)  {          //if cheacker lentgh > 2        
   var result = checker.substr(0, 2); //start at char 1 and pull first 2 chars
     document.getElementById("usage").innerHTML = result;
    }
  else{
     document.getElementById("usage").innerHTML = "1";
    }
}
```

```html
<p id="usage">6564</p>

<button onclick="extractFunction()">Extract it</button>
```